# Leverage browser caching issue with Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-ec2, browser-cache

I have a **rails app** deployed on **Amazon EC2 server** - **Nginx & Unicorn**

I have to enable **Browser Caching**.

Here is the code of my **nginx.conf**

```
upstream unicorn {
server unix:/tmp/unicorn.nqlive.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
listen 80;
listen 443 ssl;
server_name xyz.com;
ssl_certificate /usr/local/nginx/conf/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/nginx/conf/server.key;
root /home/ec2-user/hello/production/current/public;


location ~* \.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
expires 168h;
add_header Pragma public;
add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
location @unicorn {
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_pass http://unicorn;
}

error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
client_max_body_size 20M;
keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

All the css , images , js start giving **403 Forbidden Error** . I have also tried by changing the permission to 777 but no success.

Comment: You have to show full config.

Comment: Are they in `/home/ec2-user/hello/production/current/public`?

Comment: Well, check error.log

Answer (score 0):

Change ownership of your files to Nginx user. Web servers typically require not only read permissions but also ownership. Moreless like SSH with PEM file connections specifically require 600 permissions for the PEM file to work.